# Populate PickerView with data from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uipickerview

I have just created a firebase database which consists of having a question and 4 choices of answers and a correct answer. I am struggling to populate the picker view with the data from firebase. I have some functions which shows data from the item label which is the question and this does sort of populate however not fully. I need to implement the functions within the pickerview to populate the choices of answers. How would I go across doing this as currently the picker view is getting data from an array. The array consists of holding a question and a choice of 4 answers and a correct answer, however I need to populate the picker view from firebase.

```
class QuestionsViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var usernamelabel: UILabel! //sets username label
    @IBOutlet weak var Next: UIButton! //next button
    @IBOutlet weak var itemLabel: UILabel! //item user has selected
    @IBOutlet weak var Question: UILabel! //sets question label
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerview: UIPickerView! //sets picker view

    public var totalQuestions: Int = 0 //sets total question to 0
    public var currentQuestion = 0  //sets current question to 0
    public var totalCorrect: Int = 0 //sets totalcorrect to 0
    var itemSelected: String = "" //item selected
    var LabelText = String()
    let Exam = Questions() //uses the questions class for instances

    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
    var refHandle: UInt!




    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad() //when the app is loaded
        usernamelabel.text = LabelText //username
        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        refHandle = ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot)in
            let dataDict = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
            print (dataDict)
        })


        itemLabel.text = "" //loads the item label of whats selected
        //totalQuestions = quest.count //load the count of the array
       // itemSelected = Exam.quiz[currentQuestion][1] //initially when loaded first item is selected
       // Question.text = Exam.quiz[currentQuestion][0] //first element in first row of array

    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

        return 1 //return one component from the picker
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{



        return (Exam.quiz[0].count - 2) //6 columns but only need 4
        //array is 6 and minus 2
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?{




        let answers:[String] = Array(Exam.quiz[currentQuestion][1...4]) // which 4 columns to show
        return answers[row] //returns the answer

    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){

        let answers:[String] = Array(Exam.quiz[currentQuestion][1...4]) //calculates what the item you selected is called
        itemSelected = answers[row]

    }

    @IBAction func NextAction(_ sender: Any){

        ref.child("Questions").child("Q\(currentQuestion)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let quest = value?["Question"] as? String ?? ""
            self.Question.text = quest

            // ...
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

       // currentQuestion = currentQuestion //moves onto next question and increments

        if(itemSelected == Exam.quiz[currentQuestion - 1][5]){ //checks if item selection is same as column 6
            totalCorrect += 1
            itemLabel.text = String(totalCorrect) + "/" + String(totalQuestions)
        }

        if(currentQuestion < Exam.quiz.count) { // if the current question is lower than the count/size of array
            pickerview.reloadAllComponents()
            itemSelected = Exam.quiz[currentQuestion][1]
            Question.text = Exam.quiz[currentQuestion][0]
        } else {
            pickerview.isHidden = true
            Question.text = "You have finished"
            Next.isHidden = true
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to just call the delegate of the pickerview in viewdidload..   pickeview.delegate = self